# WCF web service error: The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

I am trying to create a restful wcf web service.    When I try to connect to the service through the client I get the following error:

> > **The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility. ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for this application. Turn off ASP.NET compatibility mode in the web.config or add the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the service type with RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or 'Required'.**

Others have had problems, but they fixed it through changes to their web.config.  I have implemented their fix, but still the problem exists.  here is my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior" >
           <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="myfirstwcf">
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                  contract="Imyfirstwcf" />
        <endpoint address="ws2" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
                  contract="Imyfirstwcf" />
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="Imyfirstwcf" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled= "true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793233/why-does-aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsmode-allowed-fix-this-error

Answer (score 110, accepted):

On your main service you could mark your service as:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
        RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

From http://forums.silverlight.net/t/21944.aspx

Comment: Thanks that worked. incase anyone else is using vb.net...the syntax is: <AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)>  What I really need is a good example of creating restful wcf with vb.net syntax, but all I can find is C# examples, and I spend my time trying to convert to vb.net.  If anyone knows of good sample code in vb.net please let me know, or send me a link

Comment: I spent about 12 hours trying to chase down "The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error" before I found this answer, and it fixed my issue! =P  Thanks!

Comment: I've got this when i switch my OS from Win7 to Win8. Even debugging the project doesn't works. Something on IIS8 makes this configuration necessary on WCF Services. Thank you Steve! :)

Comment: worked like a charm..also dont forget to Add System.ServiceModel.Activation namespace in your using list

Answer (score 56):

it will work :

you have change this lines in code or add the line in web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" /> 
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, changing ````aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"````

Comment: This worked for me.  The added benefit of this method is that it does not require you to recompile the source code.

Comment: I'd prefer to make a config file change than to make a change in the code files.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has a lot of services and services are created using custom `ServiceHostFactory`, then `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute` can also be set in `CreateServiceHost` method.

**Example:**

```
public class HostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        var host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        //other relevent code to configure host's end point etc
        if (host.Description.Behaviors.Contains(typeof(AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute)))
        {
            var compatibilityRequirementsAttribute = host.Description.Behaviors[typeof(AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute)] as AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute;
            compatibilityRequirementsAttribute.RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed;
        }
        else
        {
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute() { RequirementsMode =AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed});
        }
        return host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, as per the latest documentation you need to do 2 things,

1.For your service class:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "url")]
public class Service : IService
{
}
```

2.For web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```