# Regarding UriTemplate usage in WCF and AspNetCompatibilityRequirements usage WCF

Tags: wcf

1) i never design or develop any wcf service with rest approach. so when i was going through lots of article of similar kind then i notice one keyword that is UriTemplate.

so like to know what is UriTemplate and what it does ?

i have seen few different kind of UriTemplate as follows below

```
UriTemplate = "/X/{y}?Z={z}")
UriTemplate = "/GetPeople"
UriTemplate = "/GetPerson?id={id}"
UriTemplate = "Auth/Login"
```

what does it mean /X/{y}?Z={z} or GetPerson?id={id} ??

what does this mean UriTemplate = "Auth/Login" when method name is **AuthLogin**

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Auth/Login",  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public bool AuthLogin(string userName, string password)
    {
        var provider = (SqlMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
        if (provider.ValidateUser(userName, password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

2) what is `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =  AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]` and what it does or confirm.
if some one do not use it then what may happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URITemplate` is used to control the template based generation of WCF REST Service URIs.  To enable customization of the URI for each method and verb combination, WCF added the ability to define the URI for each resource by using a special template syntax.  This syntax allows you to define, with replaceable tokens, the URI structure you'd like each method to represent in conjunction with the HTTP verb.

The following article provides a good overview:
http://debugmode.net/2010/06/02/urirest1/

Regarding the second question about `AspNetCompatibilityRequirements`, the following StackOverflow post seems to provide good details:
[Why does AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed fix this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793233/why-does-aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsmode-allowed-fix-this-error)

Comment: i though that u would explain the meaning of my given uri template but u did not. if possible discuss about those in my question.